# Should Postgres timezone be changed from UTC?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, timezone, utc

I have a cron that runs a script in my rails app hourly looking for new transactions to run. Typically this only picks up new transactions set to start on the current day, until midnight UTC, when all the following day's transactions become due. My rails app is operating in Central Time, but Postgres is set to UTC. Since I'm using a scope with a `where` clause, and `now()` to compare the dates, transactions for the new day run in the early evening (in the US). Is there a downside to switching Postgres's timezone to Central Time? From what I can tell, it will record all timestamps in UTC regardless, but will run queries based on its timezone setting.

Comment: PostgreSQL isn't do it, Rails is doing it. PostgreSQL has `timestamp` and `timestamp with time zone` types but Rails wants to use the `timestamp` type and make everything (implicitly) UTC inside the database. Various ActiveRecord Ruby-to-PostgreSQL type conversions will include the time zone adjustment behind your back, this can cause problems if some logic is in the SQL (such as `now()`) and some is in Rails.

Comment: [This closely related answer may be of help.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

Answer (score 1):

You should always use UTC inside the application, and only perform conversions to other timezones at the edge of the application where necessary - such as in controllers or views.

In your query, perform some [date manipulation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-datetime.html) on `now()` to translate it to the timezone you need.